# Get all jQuery/JavaScript event subscriptions of element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

all forms on my website are getting submitted by AJAX. And I can't find where it is implemented.

When I look into HTML I see the plain `<form>` with submit button, but form is always sent asynchronously.

I know that some `.js` file contains something like this:

```
$("form").onsubmit(function(e) {
   var form = $(this).serialize();
   $.post(......
   e.preventDefault();
   .....
});
```

But I cant find this code. My JavaScript doesn't do such things.

Where I can get the event subscriptions for events of particular element (or all form elements)?

Thank you

UPD:

Ok. It seems I found the suspect. When I remove script reference to jquery.mobile my forms are sending normally.
How to disable sending by AJAX for one particular form?

Comment: Who wrote the original code?

Comment: Although you're probably looking for the actual code that makes the AJAX call, you can always watch your requests with the NET tab in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I recommend you to read http://gil.badall.net/2013/03/07/on-javascript-events/ which points you to http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: Yes, I need to find out which code was sending the last AJAX POST which I see in Firebug

Comment: Ok. It seems I found the suspect. When I remove script reference to jquery.mobile my forms are sending normally. How to disable sending by AJAX for one particular form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download chrome, select an element. Then at the right side of your developer tools (Where you also have css). There is a tab called "Event listeners". You can see all events bound to the element here - and their location (file + line number). Note that you need to check parents aswell, as events bubble up the dom tree.

If you are a firefox user, You can use firebug to see the events.

You can also see the events by using the below code. But this will not tell you which script and line.

```
$('selector').data('events');
```

Like this on this page:

```
$('#show-editor-button input').data('events')
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the event subscription in jquery-mobile lib using Chrome dev-tools. I commented the event subscription lines out and now everything works perfect. Forms are getting sended synchronously with postbacks. Thank you one more time